# Scala Lift - How to use 3rd party JAR files in project

Tags: scala, lift, imgscalr

I've done this before but can't seem to remember what folder to create or where to put jar files.

I'm attempting to include an independently developed JAR file into my Lift project, so I can do:

```
import org.imgscalr._
```

And use it etc.

Any help much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick bad way:

Add the `.jar` file to your `nameofproject/lib/` folder, it should automatically be added to your classpath.

Proper way: Use SBT

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "org.imgscalr"   %  "imgscalr-lib"      % "4.2"
)
```

This library is published to Maven Central, right [**HERE**](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.imgscalr%22).